# Passing Parameter from URL string in Header() redirect to another page in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, header, request, urlstream

I want to pass the URL string data to dashboard.php from login.php
here I have just a login auth whereas the data present in the URL is been carried from homepage.php form to login via URL string, I want to carry forward this string to dashboard

The code which gets redirected from dashboard.php for login session for login:

```
<?php
if(!$_SESSION["UserName"])
{
    //Do not show protected data, redirect to login...
     $FullName = $_REQUEST["name_"]; 
     $Subject = $_REQUEST["subject_"];
     $Phone = $_REQUEST["phone_"];
     $Email = $_REQUEST["email_"];
     $Message = $_REQUEST["message_"];
    header("Location: login.php?name_=$FullName&subject_=$Subject&phone_=$Phone&email_=$Email&message_=$Message");

}

?>
```

URL String shown in login.php after redirect:

```
http://localhost/youngants/login.php?name_=Sharayu%20Bhave&subject_=hello&phone_=9876543210&email_=bhave.sharayu@gmail.com&message_=hh
```

After the user logs in and redirects to dashbord.php I get a blank URL string and data is not displayed, see below :-

```
http://localhost/youngants/dashboard.php?name_=&subject_=&phone_=&email_=&message_=
```

My login code where I pass the same URL again via header(), see below :-

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))  
                                    {  
                                        $username=$_POST['Username'];  
                                        $user_pass=$_POST['password'];  
                                        $encrypt_pass = md5($user_pass);


                                        $check_user="select * from tbl_logindetails WHERE UserName='".$username."' AND Password='".$encrypt_pass."'";
                                        $run=mysqli_query($connection,$check_user); 



    if(mysqli_num_rows($run))  
                                            {  
                                                //echo "<script>window.open('www.google.com','_self')</script>"; 
                                                header("Location: dashboard.php?name_=$FullName&subject_=$Subject&phone_=$Phone&email_=$Email&message_=$Message");                                  

                                                $_SESSION['UserName']= $username; //here session is used and value of $user_email store in $_SESSION.  


                                            }  
                                            else 
                                            {  

                                              echo "<script>alert( 'Error in Registering Useer, Please try again later' )</script>";  
                                            }  
                                        }
```

My html form from which i take data :-

```
 <form class="form ajax-contact-form" method="" action="dashboard.php">
                            <div class="alert alert-success hidden" id="contact-success">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok "></span> &nbsp;
                                <strong>Success!</strong> Thank you for your message.
                            </div>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger hidden" id="contact-error">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove "></span> &nbsp;
                                <strong>Error!</strong> Oops, something went wrong.
                            </div>
                            <div class="row col-p10">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="mb10">
                                        <input type="text" name="name_" id="name_" required class="form-control" placeholder=" Full Name * ">


                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="mb10">
                                        <input type="text" name="subject_" id="subject_" required class="form-control" placeholder=" Subject *">
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row col-p10">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="mb10">
                                        <input type="text" name="phone_" id="phone_" class="form-control" placeholder=" Phone">
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="mb10">
                                        <input type="email" name="email_" id="email_" required class="form-control" placeholder=" Email Address *">
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <label>
                                <textarea name="message_" id="message_" cols="30" rows="10" required class="form-control" placeholder=" Message *"></textarea>
                            </label>
                            <div class="mb40"></div>
                            <div class="clearfix">
                            <!-- Enter your google site key here for captcha -->
                               <div class="pull-right xs-pull-left xs-box">



                                </div>  
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-icon btn-e" value="submit" name="submit"><i class="icon icon_mail_alt"></i> Sumbit</button>



                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

I want is to take the above URL from login.php back to dashboard.php and display this data there on dashboard.php. Note, I have only the user id pass auth on login where the URL link carries data from homepage.php.

Comment: eiser to just shove it in a session

Comment: i do not want to keep sesson variables for security reason as user doesnt have access to only selected fields as per their subscriptions so i am using $REQUEST to just use the variable and on submit it clears off.

Comment: You don't want to use sessions for security reasons but you're willing to use GET? hmm...

Comment: Sessions are more secure rather than GET since sessions are stored in the server side, meanwhile the GET requests will be visible on the screen, browser history and connection logs.

Comment: sessions are used in my code but for some privacy transactions only, here where i want to show data to user so no use of using sessions nd simply pass it by URL string, the user confirms, he logsout, finish url filled is resert. @FiratAkandere

Comment: how does the user get from login.php back to dashboard?

Comment: @Dagon buddy its like this... on my homepage i have a form where user contacts to the developer for suggesstions, here when the user submits form on homepage i take the user to his personal dashboard to confirm the question he asked, but if the user not logged in he is redirected to login.php with the parameter of his asked question via URL, after login i redirect back to dashboard taking the same paramter but i get a blank value in URL as data is not displayed.

Comment: so the dashboard redirect url should be populated wit the variables

Comment: I think you should show us also the html form

Comment: @Dagon i have posted the URL from login that i redirect and the blank URL field i get in the dashboard.php, please see question i edited it for ua needed info

Comment: @FiratAkandere i hv posted the html form also as per your need, plz see question.

Comment: Is this an ajax form? Does it send form data by using POST method?

Comment: no buddy not an ajax form, i have generated the form css which loks like ajax form, the class name i gave so the i understand the css class while development @FiratAkandere

Comment: Be careful with SQL injection here - this will get hacked easily!

Answer (score 0):

on login, when redirecting to dashboard your URL is

```
 header("Location: dashboard.php?name_=$FullName&subject_=$Subject&phone_=$Phone&email_=$Email&message_=$Message");
```

those variables dont exist. you need to use `$_GET['name_']` etc, the names used in the url

Comment: buddy u mean dashboard.php?name_=$_GET['name_'] like this when i redirect after login am i right??

Comment: correct, but i would drop the use of underscore in the variable names

Comment: i did as u said, i gives be the error as Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\youngants\login.php on line 38

Comment: this is what i did   header("Location: dashboard.php?name_=$_GET['name_']&subject_=$_GET['subject_']&phone_=$_GET['phone_']&email_=$_GET['email_']&message_=$_GET['message_']");

Comment: try `header("Location: dashboard.php?name_=".$_GET['name_']."&subject_=".$_GET['subject_']."&phone_=".$_GET['phon‌​e_']."&email_=".$_GET['email_']."&message_=".$_GET['message_']);
`

Comment: @ChinmayBapat store those $_GET values in separate variable and use them inside the `header()` function.

Comment: ^why, no need, extra memory usage for no gain

Comment: @dagon no buddy still a blank URL on dashboard.php  http://localhost/youngants/dashboard.php?name_=&subject_=&phone_=&email_=&message_= .... i tried nds checked as u told above

Comment: add `print_r($_GET)` and post the result

Comment: @dagon u mean print_r($_GET)['name'] ??

Comment: @Dagon m not getn u, can u plz tell me what exactly i need to add after  dashboard.php?name_=

Comment: @Dagon i did this header("Location: dashboard.php?print_r($_GET)"); and what i got in dashboard.php url is http://localhost/youngants/dashboard.php?print_r(Array) with Notice: Undefined index: name_ in C:\xampp\htdocs\youngants\dashboard.php on line 405 error message